# Calling constructor of parent class in static method of child class

Tags: javascript, class

I got a problem with calling super inside of the child static method.

```
const _todos = [];

class Todo {
  constructor(title) {
    this.title = title;
    this.id = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    _todos.push({title, id: this.id});

    console.log(`Todo ID: ${this.id}. DONT FORGET IT!`);
  }

  static TodoerVersion = '1.8';

  static removeTodo(id) {
    const todoIndex = _todos.findIndex(t => t.id == id);
    _todos.splice(todoIndex, 1);
  }
}

class TodoV2 extends Todo {
  static addTodo(title) {
    super(title);
  }

  static addDescription(todo, description) {
    todo.description = description;
  }

  static TodoerVersion = '2.0';
};

new TodoV2("play guitar");
```

Why does it not work?
But if i call `super` in normal method, it would works just fine.

Comment: `removeTodo` shouldnt be static!

Comment: Since `addTodo` is static, there's not an instance to look the parent for. Maybe you can try `new Todo(title)`

Comment: You should not be using `static` methods for instanced behavior. Remove the `static` modifiers on the methods in your `TodoV2` class. See [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) about using the `static` modifier in classes.

Comment: But in my proposed solution, you'd end up creating a new instance of `Todo` each time you call `TodoV2.addTodo(...)`, pretty useless. Are you sure you need all these methods to be static?

Comment: I know that `TodoV2.addTodo(...)` is useless, but im interested in understanding the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super` is only callable within the constructor function of a class.

Two answers for you:

1. The question you actually asked.
2. What I think you should do instead. :-)

#### Answering the question you asked:

JavaScript is **very** special in this regard: `this` has meaning in `static` methods (as long as you call them correctly, e.g. `TodoV2.addTodo("title")`): it's the constructor function you called the static method on. And a subclass constructor function inherits from its superclass constructor function (yes, really). So you can access the constructor function for the parent class using `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)` in the `static` method:

```
// This is something unusual that JavaScript actually does support
static addTodo(title) {
    const ctor = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    return new ctor(title);
}
```

To handle the case where the user may have called `addTodo` in a way that doesn't set `this`, you might do something like this to default to `TodoV2` if `this` is `undefined`:

```
static addTodo(title) {
    const ctor = Object.getPrototypeOf(this ?? TodoV2);
    return new ctor(title);
}
```

#### What I think you should do instead

You shouldn't be using a static method for this. Instead, define a constructor for `TodoV2`:

```
class TodoV2 extends Todo {
    constructor(title, description) {
        super(title);
        this.description = description ?? "";
    }

    static addTodo(title) { // Why no `description`?
        return new this(title); // Or `new TodoV2(title)`
    }
}
```

You might also look into the `Symbol.species` pattern if you want subclasses to create instances of superclasses.

Comment: FWIW, I go into this unusual feature of JavaScript where subclass constructor functions inherit from superclass constructor functions in Chapter 4 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys* covering ES2015-ES2020. I also cover the `Symbols.species` pattern. Links in my profile if you're interested.